# Does the definition of the metre have to take into account spacetime curvature?

Tags: speed-of-light, measurements

The definition of the [metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre#Distance_travelled_by_light_in_a_specified_time) is:

> The metre is the length of the path travelled by light in vacuum
>   during a time interval of 1/299792458 of a second

Does this have to be modified in a gravitational field or is it a constant independent of spacetime curvature?

Comment: How much curvature do you have? :-)

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking a metre is a metre no matter where you measure it? ds^2 is invariant, right? What am I missing here?